# How you do you create a bash script that will run automatically when Unity startups as a user instead of root?

Tags: scripts

I have a shell script that is being run automatically under ~/.config/autostart/mining.desktop

I have it setup so that the script runs after Unity is loaded.

It seems to work at startup but if i close the bash window, the process continues to run in the bg as root. How do I setup my desktop file so that the mining script closes as soon as I close the bash window?

My desktop file is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
   Exec=gnome-terminal --command "/user/local/claymore/mine.sh" 
   Hidden=false
   NoDisplay=false
   X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

"Top" reports the ethdcrimer is running as user root.

Answer (score 0):

To make this happen use the `cron` tool to create a cron job for particular user:

1. Run:

   ```
   crontab -u <useranme> -e
   ```
2. Then add this line or similar based on your code:

   ```
   @reboot /user/local/claymore/mine.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
   ```